# Daily Health Routine and gaining weight suggestion

Tags: workout-routines, weight-gain, routine

I am 23 years old, 5'8" in height. My weight is 56 kg.
My daily schedule is busy, sometimes I can not take my meals on time.

I should gain some muscle as my age is growing, looking like a skinny man.
My daily routine is as follows:

- 9 AM wake up
- 9:30 breakfast
- 10 AM go to office
- 3 PM have my lunch
- 8:30 back from office
- 10 PM have dinner
- 11 PM - 2 AM work

and right now I have around 30 minutes to excercise in the morning.
I dont have enough time to go to gym, so in this situtation I am thinking of exercising in my home with some small instruments like dumbbells, push-ups, etc.

What will be the healthy and perfect change for me to get some weight?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much are you eating, and what kind of food?

Comment: I am eating regular foods like,three slice bread+egg+vegetables in morning,lunch  may be briyinai(rice mix with mutton)/fried chicken/burger and @ dinner rice with meat/fish.thats all

Answer (score 2):

It's all about diet and exercise.  To start with, start keeping a journal of what and when you eat (and how much).  Simple short term steps would be:

- go to a local nutrition store (GNC for example) and get some Whey protein to have on a daily basis
- vitamins
- to gain 'mass' you need to lift weights - get some dumbbells for your house - I would recommend 10lb, 35lb and 50lb pairs - and a bench to work from
- base exercises, including: squats, bench/shoulder press and rows should be part of your 3-4 day a week routine.
- get some reading done: New Rules of LIfting for example - to get ideas on workout routines and example exercises
- set aside 45 minutes to 1 hour the 3-4 times a week for your workout.....(get up a little earlier)