# What are the most up to date consolidated daily health maintenance measures?

Tags: health, maintenance

Title could be enough. But since this question is so simple that it looks a bit absurd or obvious...

Unlike many questions [out there in this site](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1721/daily-health-routine-and-gaining-weight-suggestion), I'm looking for [fitness (rest included)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_fitness) in the health sense, in opposition to aesthetics or body improvement.

I'm not talking crazy here in listing these examples, which I believe are world wide common sense:

- Eat at least 3 meals daily: *breakfast*, *lunch* and *dinner*. I'd bet most languages even have those 3 separated words to describe each of those meals. If not, they certainly do have this concept.
- Have around 8 hours of sleep, every day, despite recent studies.
- Brush and floss - rinse doesn't matter.
- Wash your hands (notice *bath* isn't required daily - not world wide at least).

Question here is: what else is there? Sunscreen, maybe? I'd like to know what is, today, considered **consolidated** things that every single human being should do **daily** to **maintain** good health - including nutrition and even, eventually, exercises. For any age or size, if that wasn't clear.

Comment: This question is far too broad, I could say exercise 30 minutes a day and it could be correct. So while I admire your mission to simply be fit, this is not the way to do it

Comment: An apple a day...

Comment: Note that "general health" question are off-topic as stated in the [faq]. "Up-to-date" things also aren't timeless or universal. If standard change, this question might be closed as "too locazlied" as well. Focus on something specific (anticipate what answers you might get) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I agree that this question is too broad. It's kind of like "what should I do across all parts of my life to be optimally healthy according to all measures?"

Comment: Actually, the best way to modify the question might be to focus on the **measures** instead of the **methods**. More people agree on blood lipids than the diet that will achieve them.

Comment: I was expecting a very detailed answer, or a very good resource (such as a whole website dedicated to this) which I am not aware of. @Dave, I tried to narrow it down to daily measures and broadly consolidated. I don't think it's too broad due to that. And yes, I agree focusing on measures.

Comment: @Matt I did look the FAQ but I've missed the "general health" point there. Sorry. This is a General Health question indeed. Can you point a SEN site in which this question wouldn't be off topic? [I've tried skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8652/what-are-the-most-up-to-date-consolidated-daily-health-maintenance-measures) with no success too.

Comment: @Cawas As far as I'm aware, there isn't a site for that subject in the [SE network](http://stackexchange.com/sites). There is a [Health proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6160/health) but I can't say when or if that site will be launched. You can commit it though and perhaps it might get some ground. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Cawas And as you've probably already read on Skeptics, [don't cross-post to multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Comment: @MattChan aight. thanks. Sorry again for the cross-posting.

Comment: @MattChan by the way, reason I've missed the "general health" point is because it's listed under "What kind of questions can I ask here?", even if it's also under "not about". I see no reason why that second list shouldn't be under the second section specifically made for that, like [it is under philosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/faq), for instance.

Comment: @Cawas that's because we moderators can only edit that top part and this style is mimicked on a lot of other sites (due to this limitation). We know its not ideal and also a reason why we've advocated changing our name to make it more Sports-centric, but sadly this hasn't happened

Comment: @Cawas Our scope has had issues in the past, and we have had the need to explicitly state those items in the [faq] in order to drive and shape the kind of community we want on this site. Anyway, we shouldn't be using the comments here for this. If you have more to discuss, please find us in the [chat] or bring it to the [meta].

Comment: @Ivo, Matt, copied. Thanks yet once again! I'll leave it as it is. I'm just glad you were aware. :-)

Answer (score 2):

### There is no common sense.

There is so little consensus on most issues that I doubt we'll have many answers outside of the medical field.

- Don't contaminate your wounds or food with harmful bacteria. [But if you're antiseptic, that causes problems too](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/guest-blog/2011/07/05/scientists-discover-that-antimicrobial-wipes-and-soaps-may-be-making-you-and-society-sick/).
- Eat food. That's about as much as everybody can agree on. Number, timing, content, and even definition of food is hotly contested by reasonable people. For kicks, compare government recommendations, the Paleo diet, and vegans.
- Don't smoke. (There are a huge number of other "don'ts" that I will omit for brevity.)
- Floss and brush your teeth. I don't think this is disputed, but I wouldn't be surprised.
- Avoid a sedentary lifestyle. What that means in terms of quantity and types of activity is [hotly contested](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/3651/1771) by reasonable people.

Sunscreen is hotly contested by reasonable people. (There are benefits of direct sunlight, and sunscreen may prevent those while allowing cancer-causing rays. Or we might just use the stuff poorly.) We don't understand our need for sleep, and some people can get highly varying amounts while retaining normal function. There is no scientific agreement on which supplements help or harm, and how much, and for whom.

This is a situation where we would like the science to be much clearer and in more agreement than it actually is. (Several of the points regarding the difficulty of science regarding health & fitness can be extrapolated from [this answer regarding strength training](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/5775/1771) and [this critique of the recent Red Meat Is Satan scare](http://robbwolf.com/2012/03/14/red-meat-part-healthy-diet/).)

Comment: Really, this whole answer only tells me I'm terrible at expressing my questions, most of times... :-( I am basically asking inside the medical field, if that wasn't clear. ;-)